# How to render an MVC action to string without HTTP context?

Tags: model-view-controller, action, render

I need to render MVC action without HTTP context (I'm using quartz.net scheduling library, I'd like to render the action to string in quartz job).

How do I create an HTTP context, instantiate MyController and execute MyController.MyAction() so I get it in the quartz job as string?

**Edit 1:**
Problem is non trivial. I looked for other posts on stack overflow but all of them seem to cover the situation where you are wihtin a context of web request. In my case HttpContext.Current is null.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Razor Engine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com) successfully for a while but it has some limitations; you can't use partial views, it's not thread-safe and most damning, studio doesn't recognize your .cshtml files as razor files since you're not really in an ASP.net MVC project so you get no intellisense.

I am therefore also looking for a better solution as well. Have you found any?

Ideally I'd want to be able to directly call a controller action and get the html.